# Auto resize custom text field for multiple lines label

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uilabel

I've a custom text field in which I'm adding an error label below text field. I want to resize this custom text field so that it expands with multiple line error label and doesn't overlap with other fields below it. In IB I've pinned view properly so that is not an issue.

How to fix it?

[image: Screenshot]

```
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: CustomTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: CustomTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        emailTextField.setError("Multiple line error. Multiple line error. Multiple line error. Multiple line error.")
    }
}

class CustomTextField: UITextField {

    var bottomBorder = UIView()
    var errorLabel = UILabel()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.initialize()

        // Setup Bottom-Border
        // ....

        errorLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addSubview(errorLabel)
        errorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomBorder.bottomAnchor, constant: 4).isActive = true
        errorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        errorLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        errorLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        errorLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        errorLabel.sizeToFit()
    }

    func initialize() {
        self.text = ""
        self.clearError()

        // ...
    }
    func setError(error: String) {
        self.errorLabel.text = error
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = false
        self.setNeedsLayout()
        self.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    func clearError() {
        self.errorLabel.text = ""
        self.errorLabel.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITextField` is only 1 line you need to use `UITextView` or better do

```
class CustomView: UIView {
   let textfield = UITextField() 
   let bottomBorder = UIView()
   let errorLabel = UILabel()
   .....
}
```

So the view will expand according to sum of textfield height , border height and label text height

Comment: Requirement is to use UITextField. The problem is with another label which I'm adding below text field and not with the text field's text itself. I want to have text field and error label below it as part of CustomTextField. The text inside text field is only one line. The label below text field is multiple line which I want to auto resize. Is it possible in my setup above?

Comment: if you did `emailTextField.clipsToBounds = true` you won't see the error label or see it clipped as it's shown out content of textfield and there is no bottom anchor to hook the label bottom with  which is the basis behind auto resize as the border view is the textfield bottom you have to use answer as said

Comment: Yes you are right, it doesn't seem to be possible. I'll have to add error label via IB then. Tx for the reply.